# How to get a stream from HttpService in NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, stream, nestjs

I'm creating a NestJS application and I need to pass a stream as an argument to some function. And I want to use nest's HttpService to get me this stream.

I'm trying to use Axios' parameter called `responseType`

But this code seems to return just string instead of a stream I want

```
    const { data } = await this.httpService.get(url, {
      responseType: 'stream'
    }).toPromise();
```

How can I make Nest's HttpService return me a stream?